# ListView edit is not switching cell to input state

Tags: java, events, listview, javafx

I have a ListView with table names in it and an add button.

```
tablesListView.setEditable(true);
tablesListView.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
tablesListView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
addTableButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent evt) {
        tablesListView.getItems().add("");
        tablesListView.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
        tablesListView.edit(tablesListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    }
});
```

So when i click on some cell in the list it switches its state to the TextField, but that's not working with the button, the cell becomes selected, but not switched. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
tablesListView.setEditable(true);
tablesListView.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
tablesListView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

final Timeline animation = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.1),
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                tablesListView.edit(tablesListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
            }
        }));
animation.setCycleCount(1);

addTableButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent evt) {
        tablesListView.getItems().add("");
        tablesListView.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
        animation.play();
    }
});
```

Actually `Platform.runLater()` works, but only occasionally, cause it runs the runnable in "some unspecified time in the future". So you need to specify the time when the edit command should run by  for instance the timeline in my code example. The edit command postponed for 0.1 sec.

Comment: No, didn't help. I'm using jfx factory TextFieldListCell.forListView() doc - http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldListCell.html

Comment: @JohnGray Unfortunately yes it is.. But. You can beautify it by doing make up, like writing util class and methods :).